# Вычесть из каждого элемента data frame число

Tags: математика, r

У меня есть data frame размера 7х7, и необходимо сделать следующее:

1. Найти минимальный элемент в каждой строке.
2. В каждой строке
   вычесть из элементов соответствующее минимальное значение. Грубо
   говоря, провести редукцию матрицы по строкам.
3. Найти минимальный элемент в каждом столбце.
4. Сделать аналогичное из п.2 только для столбцов.

То, что вышло написать:

Пункт 1:

```
min_row <- apply(tabl,1,min)
```

Пункт 2:

```
tabl_w <- tabl-min_row
```

Пункт 3:

```
min_col <- apply(tabl_w,2,min)
```

Пункт 4:

Как сделать его без циклов - я не знаю.

Есть одна мысль, это транспонировать data frame, и сделать так, как в пункте 2. Но я думаю есть более лучшее решение.

Буду очень сильно благодарен за помощь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможностей `apply` достаточно:

```
set.seed(42)

tabl <- matrix(abs(rnorm(3*3)), 3, 3)

tabl_w <- apply(tabl, 1, function(x) x - min(x))

apply(tabl_w, 2, function(x) x - min(x))
```

Comment: apply, сам транспонирует матрицу когда выполняю tabl_w <- apply(tabl, 1, function(x) x - min(x)). Можно ли как-то этого избежать? Как я понял, даже если он делает расчеты по строкам, то все равно записывает ответы по столбцам

Comment: Где же там транспонирование?